# Inserting in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

```
    unsigned int j   = 0;
    openListIterator = openListVector.begin ();
    while (exitPointDetailsVector[lowestWeightedPointInOpenList.pointId].branchesVector[m].connectedExitPoint >= openListVector[j].pointId)
           && (openListIterator <= openListVector.end()))
    {
        // Move the iterator.
        openListIterator++;
        // Move the index.
        j++;
    }

    // Insert in the vector in the required position.
    listStruct objOpenListStruct;
    objOpenListStruct.pointId       = exitPointDetailsVector[lowestWeightedPointInOpenList.pointId].branchesVector[m].connectedExitPoint;
    objOpenListStruct.weight        = exitPointDetailsVector[lowestWeightedPointInOpenList.pointId].weight + exitPointDetailsVector[lowestWeightedPointInOpenList.pointId].branchesVector[m].distance;
    objOpenListStruct.parentPointId = exitPointDetailsVector[lowestWeightedPointInOpenList.pointId].exitPoint;

    ***********openListVector.insert (openListIterator, objOpenListStruct);
```

This code is under a for loop.
But I have put the proper the iterator initialization, still I am getting a segmentation fault, on the starred line.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you post the loop & what exactly it seg faults on?

Comment: First of all , if you want to insert elements in between an vector...then this container is certainly not a good option to use. vectors will be more efficient for adding data at the end. Also inserting data invalidates the previously obtained iterators and reallocations. Would recommend you to use deque or list for insertions in between

Comment: A side-note: it seems that you're trying to maintain a sorted collection, and the code would be much simpler if you had used a set. (Unless you REALLY care about performance)

Comment: @Als If you read carefully, you'll find that I have mentioned that the code is segfaulting on the starred line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement `openListIterator <= openListVector.end()`, if you reach `openListIterator == openListVector.end()`, then you're going to have a segfault, because when the code reaches `openListIterator++`, your iterator becomes "out of bound"

Try `openListIterator != openListVector.end()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint. You can not use operator<= on iterators :

```
openListIterator <= openListVector.end()
```

therefore your iterator might not be good after all.

Comment: That should be a syntax error then or a warning? Anyways, !=, < have solved the bug. Thanks.

Comment: @Anisha Right. Bad wording. Should have been "should not" instead of "can not"

Comment: @VJo Yes and no.  "Cannot" in general---`<=` is only legal with random access iterators.  "Should not" always, as the standard idiom for a loop does use `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate advice is: don't do that. When you want to maintain a collection of items in sorted order, you should probably use an `std::set` (unless the insertion is relatively unusual). If you are going to use a sorted vector, you might as well take advantage of its being sorted and use a binary search to find the insertion point (e.g., with `std::lower_bound`).

It looks like the problem you're currently experiencing is an invalid iterator when you need/want to add to the end of the collection. This (among other issues) would be handled automatically by using the pre-packaged search algorithm (or an `std::set` or `std::multiset`).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what could be the effect of:

```
       && (openListIterator <= openListVector.end()))
```

Indeed, in the first part of the while clause, you don't use `openListIterator`, so it could well be that the loop is enteres when `openListIterator` is `openListVector.end()` and then it gets incremented. So, when you do the insert you get the segmentation fault...

Could you check for this condition when you have the segmentation fault?

If this is the cause of the problem, you could use instead:

```
       && (openListIterator < openListVector.end()))
```

Comment: Common, I should be thankful to you for posting here not the vice versa :)

Comment: I mean, you checked all the answers, not just the one that first solved your problem and that you accepted... that is good S.O. citizenship, I think... :-)

Comment: Actually, I have been a regular resident of `LinuxQuestions.org` for past 3 years now, therefore I am aware of the forum manners. :)